# How to treat small number within square root

Tags: approximation, radicals

guys.I am reading a math book. It has a equation shown as follows,

$\sqrt{(1+\Delta^2)}$

And then,since $\Delta$ is very small, it can be written as,

$\sqrt{(1+\Delta^2)} = (1+\frac12\Delta^2)$

What is the theory behind this equation?

Comment: do you know about Taylor polynomials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use $\epsilon$ instead of $\Delta^2$, and write it as
$$\sqrt{1+\epsilon}$$
Then,
$$\sqrt{1+\epsilon}=1+\frac{1}{2}\epsilon$$
Squaring both sides, we find that
$$1+\epsilon=1+\epsilon+\frac{1}{4}\epsilon^2$$
This is true if $\epsilon$ is small enough that $\epsilon^2$ can be neglected.

The first two terms of the MacLaurin series for $\sqrt{1+x}$ are
$$\sqrt{1+x}\approx 1+\frac{1}{2}x$$
This is true for all small $x$, near $x=0$.

Comment: Does it have theorem to describe such equations?

Comment: @oilpig There's [Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem).

Answer (score 2):

If we take a **taylor** expansion for representing equation with **polynomials** it gives us:

$$\sqrt {1+x^2} = 1 + \frac {1}{2} x + \frac {1}{4} x^2 + ... $$

As when $ x $ is very small $ x^2$ is very very small which can be neglected and also for $ x^{n} $ as $ n > 2$

For that

$$\sqrt {1+x^2} \approx 1 + \frac {1}{2} x^2 $$

Edited: wrong expansion in prior formula.

Answer (score 0):

Square both sides to get $1+\Delta^2\approx 1+\Delta^2+\frac{1}{4}\Delta^4$

which is a close approximation because when $\Delta$ is very small, $\frac{1}{4}\Delta^4$ is close to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

What @Mohamed_Fadel noted is NOT true.

The correct taylor expansion for $\sqrt {1+x^2}$ at the point $x_0=0$ is:

$$\sqrt {1+x^2} = 1 + \frac {1}{2} x^2 - \frac {1}{8} x^4 + \frac {1}{16} x^6...$$

That you get by just going through the standard taylor expansion.

For getting $\sqrt{(1+\Delta^2)} = (1+\frac12\Delta^2)$, all you need to do is neglect every order following the quadratic.

@Mohamed_Fadel: You cannot treat $x^2$ like a single variable $x$ when expanding, because inner derivatives will arise when doing the Taylor expansion.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This should be a comment, not an answer.